# Find objects in list where all properties exists in another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a database structure similar to this

```
itemID   |   attributeID
------------------------
   1     |       1
   2     |       1
   1     |       2
```

I need to find a way to find all items that match on a list of attributes. I have it working where I can select items that match on ANY of the attributes, using this LINQ query

```
List<int> attributes = new List<int>(){ 1, 2};

List<int> listOfItemIDs = (from item in db.ItemsToAttributes
                           where attributes.Contains(item.attributeID)
                           select item.itemID)
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();
```

And this code will return back a list of `int`'s, specifically `{1,2}`, because itemID 1 matched on attribute 1 (and 2), and itemID 2 matched on attribute 1.

I can't figure out how to grab the list of itemID's where it matches on ALL items in the attribute list. So in the example given above, I would need it to return JUST itemID 1, because itemID one matched both on attribute 1 AND attribute 2.

I've been looking at using an `Intersect` or an `Except`, but I can't seem to get either to work.

Comment: What if we add `ID=1, Attr=3` to the list. It should still return `1` in the result?

Comment: Yes, it should still return 1 in the result. In order to achieve this, I tweaked GWhites answer, by removing the first WHERE clause (`!x.Select(y => y.attributeID).Except(attributes).Any()`) and only left the second one. (`!attributes.Except(x.Select(y => y.attributeID)).Any()`). That would return back the list where it matches on all attributes but ignores if there are extra attributes attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = db.ItemsToAttributes
               .GroupBy(x => x.itemID)
               .Where(x => !x.Select(y => y.attributeID).Except(attributes).Any() 
            && !attributes.Except(x.Select(y => y.attributeID)).Any()).Select(x => x.Key);
```

You're going to want to group them by the Item IDs so you know which attribute IDs correspond to each of your eligible Item IDs. This gives you an `IEnumerable` of `IGrouping` where the group keys are the Item IDs. Then you can use the grouped attribute ID collections and check them against the attributes collection. If all the items exist in both collections, the item ID in question has all the right attributes. The final `.Select` returns the Keys (Item IDs) of the items whose attributes match the provided list.

Comment: Perfect that was exactly what I was looking for - thanks!